# CreateProcessWithLoginW - Redirecting STDOUT

Tags: c++, winapi, stdout, redirect, stdin

What I would like is to have the process start but have the input and output all be in the same console.

```
if(CreateProcessWithLogonW(user,domain, pass, LOGON_WITH_PROFILE, NULL, cmd, 0, 0, 0, &sa, &pe))
{
    printf("[~] Process spawned with PID %X\n",  pe.dwProcessId);
}
else
{
    printf("[!] Failed to create process. Error Code: %X\n", GetLastError());
}
```

When I use this code it creates a whole new window instead of having it in the same window. Is there a way to unset  the "CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE" flag because even when I set it to 0 it still creates a new console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to help on this method:

> The CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE,
>   CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, and
>   CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP flags are
>   enabled by default— even if you do not
>   set the flag, the system functions as
>   if it were set.

It looks like Windows API doesn't allow these flags not to be set.